# client server caching / messaging buy decision

Tags: .net, caching, distributed

The use case is my client has 10 users each with their own workstations (Windows) using our dealing software (.Net / SQL), and 1 FIX server out to the market. So there's a server cache of all messages, and on each message event I want to route the incoming message to the correct local cache (1 of 10) within the LAN. I am looking for a good speed v reliability trade off. I see no reason to build this when there are already open source and commercial products out there. Which products are tried and tested and most suitable for this use case?

For example: eventstore, ncache, hazelcast, geode, ignite, gigaspaces, kafka, cassandra and more...

Answer (score 1):

Any of the said product can help you achieve reliable messaging. Since you're already using .Net in a Windows environment you might try NCache since it's written in .NET and understands the native environment.

You could use the replicated cache to get the reliability and performance will automatically add in since everything is In-Memory. The replicated cache is available in the open source version.

If you want more performance you could buy it and use the Partition of replica topology.